# Error while uploading "osmapi.OsmApi.ApiError: Request failed: 404 - Not Found - b''

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I've just started to explore Python OSM API and tried to upload a "way" into Open Street Map.

```py
import osmapi
api = osmapi.OsmApi(api = "https://api06.dev.openstreetmap.org", username = "*******", password =******)
cs = api.ChangesetCreate()
start = api.NodeCreate({"lon":39.77188512682915,"lat":40.99645466061746,"visible":True})
stop = api.NodeCreate({"lon":39.77237597107887,"lat":40.99594855924428,"visible":True})
wayPoints = [start["id"], stop["id"]]
way = api.WayCreate({"nd":wayPoints ,"visible":True})
api.ChangesetUpload([{"type":"way","action":"create","data":way}])
api.ChangesetClose()
```

After the execution, "Request failed: 404 - Not Found - b" error occurred. Am I doing something wrong or incomplete?

Comment: Not sure if StackOverflow is the right place to ask. Your question might better fit to help.openstreetmap.org/.

Comment: You may be right but I posted it APIs Github repo as issue too. Still waiting